# Scapy multiple sniff filters not working?

Tags: python, security, scapy

So I'm using this filter for sniff :

```
myfilter = 'tcp and tcp.flags.syn==1 and tcp.flags.ack==0 and tcp.flags.psh==0'

sniff(iface="myinter" , filter=myfilter , prn=mitm , count=1 )
```

and it gets packets without the specified flags as well :

i want only flags that are ACK=0, SYN=1 and PSH=0, but this is not working

i also tried not using == and just use tcp.flags.syn 1 and still didnt work

am i doing something wrong here?

UPDATE:

it looks like it gives syntax error to something as well:

tcpdump: syntax error

but when i just use tcp or TCP it doesn't give any syntax error, this error doesnt stop the program but it looks like it stops the filtering

even when i just used tcp.flags.syn==1 or   tcp.flags.syn 1 it still gave this syntax error... my scapy is 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter you are using is simply not a valid PCAP filter (hence the syntax error message). On a Unix system, you can have a look at the `pcap-filter(7)` and the `tcpdump(1)` manpages for more information about the syntax you can use.

Something like this should work:

```py
myfilter="tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack|tcp-push) == tcp-syn"
sniff(iface="myinter" , filter=myfilter, prn=mitm , count=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can i read more about the syntax of these filters outside of unix? i couldn't find this in their website? https://scapy.readthedocs.io it finds nothing when i search tcp filters

Comment: You couln't find this in Scapy's documentation because **it is not Scapy specific**. The `pcap-filter(7)` and `tcpdump(1)` in my answer refer to manual pages.